# Access c:\" my path " in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, prompt

I want to access a path in C drive when I open the command prompt I have `c:\user\myname`
where is I want to access `c:\`
so that I can access any paht I want in C

Comment: Did you actually *try* to [Google?](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=cmd+directory) First link tells you *exactly* how to. Or [Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=change+cmd+directory&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=change+cmd+directory&sc=1-20&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=bf2932ace4924c5e963b3c8eb5254cb7)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ: Did hear "already" that Google results maybe personalized, thus invalidating the universal truth of your comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change to a directory use the cd command:

```
cd C:\my\path
```

Or

```
cd \
```

To change to the root of any drive you're in.

To change drives just put its letter followed by a colon:

```
D:
```

You need to change drives first in order to change to a directory that is not in the current drive. Example:

Let's assume you're in `C:\` and you want to change to `D:\my\other\path`, so you have to issue the following commands:

```
C:\> D:
D:\> cd \my\other\path
```

Comment: “You need to change drives first in order to change to a directory that is not in the current drive.” This statement is not strictly true. You can `cd D:\my\other\path` and _then_ type `D:`. Or you can do it all in one step with `cd/d D:\my\other\path`.